# Need help understanding inheritance in PyQt5

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt5

I'm trying to organize my code into classes. In the example below, `B` and `C` need to inherit the names of the push buttons from `A` so that the buttons echo a statement when pushed. In order for me to get this to work properly, I had to create `Dummy` and inherit `B` and `C` and then created in instance of `Dummy`. It doesn't seem like this is the way I should be doing it. Is there a "better" or "more accepted" way of using multiple classes in PyQt5?

inheritance.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'inheritance.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(452, 246)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.b_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.b_pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 151, 81))
        self.b_pushButton.setObjectName("b_pushButton")
        self.c_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.c_pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 50, 151, 81))
        self.c_pushButton.setObjectName("c_pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 452, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.b_pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "B"))
        self.c_pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "C"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Main script:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from inheritance import Ui_MainWindow

class A(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()

        self.ui.b_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushB)

    def pushB(self):
        print('You pushed the "B" button')
        print()

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()

        self.ui.c_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushC)

    def pushC(self):
        print('You pushed the "C" button')
        print()

class Dummy(B, C):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Dummy()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why do you do a multiple inheritance? What is the objective of B and C? The goal of class A is clear: populating the widgets with the Ui_MainWindow class but for the other classes you don't point to a precise goal. Why does B need to inherit from A? The same for C

Comment: I thought that B and C needed to inherit from A in order to access the name of the push button.

Comment: Inheritance does not serve to access variables, that is not its goal. One of the main goals of inheritance is not to rewrite redundant code. Why is it necessary to make the connection between the clicked signal and the methods in the constructor of B and C? Why don't you make B and C classes that don't inherit from A and that are instantiated in A and make the connection there? Inheritance in PyQt5 is the same concept as inheritance in Python so I recommend deepening your concept into python inheritance by reviewing concepts and examples.

Comment: I was initially trying to make B and C not inherit from A, create an instance in A, and then make the connection but wasn't having any luck.  I will continue reading concepts and examples.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Each widget has signals that notify the change, in your case you must use https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox.html#stateChanged that sends that information. I recommend you read about the function of the signals: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html . Bye

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing what eyllanesc suggested.  I was initially trying to keep everything related to B and C in their own class because my actual code is really long, but this will do.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from inheritance import Ui_MainWindow

class A(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.B = B()
        self.C = C()

        self.ui.b_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.B.pushB)
        self.ui.c_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.C.pushC)

class B:
    def pushB(self):
        print('You pushed the "B" button')
        print()

class C:
    def pushC(self):
        print('You pushed the "C" button')
        print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = A()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What you have done is not inheritance but composition. Inheritance is expressed as A **is** B and composition is expressed as A **has** B, in your case A **has** an object B and an object C

Comment: What if I need access the name of a check box or some other widget within self.ui in class B or C? For example, what if I wanted to echo the print statements only if a check box was checked?

Comment: @Simon1 what you ask has nothing to do with inheritance; just implement `pushB` and `pushC` as part of `A`. But I'm beginning to think that you're having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you never *really* answered the first and probably most important question eyllanesc asked you: Why do you do a multiple inheritance?

Comment: I do multiple inheritance because I don't know exactly what I'm doing yet with classes haha. I was trying to get the attributes from self.ui, so I thought I needed to do multiple inheritance. I have figured out how do what I wanted and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that does what I was trying to do - access the attributes from ui so I could access them in other classes.

I ended up passing the ui object from A into the `__init__` of B and C. Not sure if this proper coding, but it works.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from inheritance import Ui_MainWindow

class A(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.B = B(self.ui)
        self.C = C(self.ui)

        self.ui.b_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.B.pushB)
        self.ui.c_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.C.pushC)

class B():
    def __init__(self, ui):
        self.ui = ui

    def pushB(self):
        if self.ui.b_checkBox.isChecked():
            print('You pushed the "B" button')
            print()
        else:
            print('Check the check box to print the correct statement.')

class C():
    def __init__(self, ui):
        self.ui = ui

    def pushC(self):
        if self.ui.c_checkBox.isChecked():
            print('You pushed the "C" button')
            print()
        else:
            print('Check the check box to print the correct statement.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = A()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```